# How do I set an association with a file upload(multer) and userId in express and psql?

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, psql

I'm trying to set user to have one image upload. This is the code I have in the router

```
const multer = require('multer')
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'uploads/')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.filename + '-' + Date.now() + '.jpg')
  }
})

const upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('image')

appRouter.post('/upload', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const uploadImage = await Image.create(req.body)
    upload(req, res, () => {
      res.json({
        uploadImage,
        success: true,
        message: 'Image uploaded'
      })
    })
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
})
```

and heres how I have it in model

```
module.exports = (db, Sequelize) => {
    return db.define('image', {})
}
```

and this as well.

```
const Image = imageModel(db, Sequelize)
User.hasOne(Image)
```

This is a fullstack express app with auth and I'm trying to enable users to upload their own images.

Heres how it looks on postman, userId is still null:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are never associating the image with an user.

You are creating the image, but don't add a user to the image. You need a way to identify the user and then associate it when creating (or after creating the image).

You'll probably need to implement way for users to identify themselves to do this.

Your model declaration implies that a User has an image, this doesn't mean that all images have an user, there may be images without users.